# Цвет погона сухопутных войск

Tags: прилагательные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какого цвета погон (под окаёмкой) - хаки?

Answer (score 1):

В армейской терминологии оттенков формы и обмундирования есть такой: защитный цвет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте разобраться по этой [статье](https://forma-odezhda.ru/encyclopedia/cveta-pogon-v-vojskah-rf/).

Официальной документации (приказов) от МО найти не удалось, какие-то битые ссылки только..

Я бы сказал, что это оливковый цвет. Защитный - это на полевой форме. Но я не специалист.

```
    Погоны  Министерства обороны (общевойсковые, погоны  сухопутных войск). 
К этой категории аксессуаров относятся изделия следующих цветов:
    оливковые (повседневные);
```